# fgets() gets does not stop when it encounters a NUL. Under what circumstance will this be a problem?

Tags: c, string, text

I understand that when using `fgets`, the program will not stop when it encounters `NUL`, namely `'\0'`. However when will this a problem and needs to be manually addressed?

My main use case for `fgets` is to get it from user input (like a better version of `scanf` to allow reading white spaces.) I cannot think of a situation where a user will want to terminates his input by typing `'\0'`.

Comment: Are you reading a binary file? If so, you should probably use `fread` instead of `fgets`.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem if you are reading a text file, which usually does not contain the `NUL` character. The user does not terminate with that character but with `EOF`. If `NUL` is present in a binary file: `fgets()` is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: It's a problem because *if* there is an embedded `\0` and text after it, it's quite difficult to detect this, so most `fgets`-using code will inadvertently discard the following text.  But "plain text" and user input don't usually contain embedded `\0` bytes, so it's usually not a problem in practice.

Comment: *I cannot think of a situation where a user will want to terminates his input by typing '\0'.* I can't, either.

Comment: @SteveSummit
Thanks for your comment. I think I have some fundamental lack of understanding what "NUL" is, especially in the context of binary file... Could you try to explain it? Thanks. (although my original question is not intended for reading binary file, but since everyone is mentioning it I am curious now).

Comment: `NUL` does not *have* a particular meaning in a binary file, where a `0` byte means whatever is relevant in the context it is being used. It is the name of one of the legacy "control characters" used in a text stream, whose value is `0`.

Comment: @Learning_man A byte with the value 0 is simultaneously (a) a byte with the value 0 and (b) the ASCII control character NUL and (c) C's special string terminator value, often represented by `\0`.  There's no magic, *except* that *if* you read in some bytes, and expect to treat them as a C string, and if those bytes might contain an embedded 0 byte, they'll prematurely and falsely be interpreted as the end of the string.

Comment: @WeatherVane
So usually a well-functioning program is meant to stop at encountering the NUL, instead of continuing to read beyond it?

Comment: @Learning_man No.  A well-functioning program for reading binary data will treat it as counted bytes, not a null-terminated string, so it won't prematurely or wrongly stop at a 0 byte.  A well-functioning program for reading text data can use appended 0 bytes as a string terminator, because well-behaved text data won't contain 0 bytes.

Comment: No. It's specific use in C is as a string *variable* terminator. If you read a line from a text file that contains `NUL` then as Steve says, the C program will automatically truncate the string at that point. But it isn't considered to be a terminator in a text *file*, and we don't write it to a text file. The `'\0'` at the end of a line read by `fgets()` is *added by `fgets()`*. It isn't usually present in the file.

Comment: Note that when you call `fgets`, and it reads a line of length, say, 5, the string you get back will contain *seven* characters: the 5 characters the user typed, and the `\n` corresponding to the carriage return the user typed, and the `\0` to terminate the string.  In this case, nobody "typed" the `\0`; it was added by code inside `fgets`.

Comment: Thx and I am starting to understand! So a well-functioning program should just ignore the embedded NUL and keep reading the rest of the file, which is not what fgets does. fgets will read it and keep reading the rest of the test, but C (to be precise, many functions in C that relies on recognizing '\0' as string terminator, such as strlen() ) could potentially mis-interpret that the string stopped in the mid-way. Right?

Comment: Yes and no: there usually *won't be a `NUL`* in the file itself. One situation where there is, is when a `struct` that contains a string member is written to a binary file, and then it's an exact dump, including the `'\0'` string terminator. But this file should not be read with `fgets()` anyway.

Comment: Great, thanks! The original question I wanted to ask is if I could use fgets as a better version of "scanf" to allow reading in white spaces, etc. Good to know at least in this case I don't have to worry about "NUL".  This discussion is super useful but getting slightly off-topic. I will go on learning about other file-reading functions. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, many people prefer to use `fgets()` and apply `sscanf()` or `strtod()` etc, to the string. But don't mix `scanf()` and `fgets()` from the same input.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Grammarly is great but has a penchant for mapping “null” to “thanks”  I spotted one and missed the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that *text* file input is usually *lines*: characters followed by a `'\n'` (expect maybe the last line).  On *reading* text input, a *null character* is not special.  It is not an alternate end-of-line.  It is just another non-`'\n'` character.

It is functions like `fgets()`, `fscanf()` append a *null character* to the read buffer to denote the end of *string*.  Now when code reads that *string*, is a *null character* a read one or the appended one?

If code uses `fgets()`, `fscanf()`, `getchar()`, etc. is not really the issue.  The issue is how should code detect *null characters* and how to handle them.

Reading a *null character* from a text stream is uncommon, but not impossible.  *Null characters* tend to reflect a problem more often than valid text data.

**Reasons *null characters* exist in a text file**

1. The text file is a wide character text file, perhaps [UTF16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) when *null characters* are common.  Code needs to read this file with `fgetws()` and related functions.
2. The text file is a binary data one.  Better to use `fread()`.
3. File is a text file, yet through error or nefarious intent, code has *null characters*.  Usually best to detect, if possible, and exit working this file with an error message or status.
4. Legitimate text file uncommonly using *null characters*.  `fgets()` is not the best tool.  Likely need crafted input functions or other extensions like `getline()`.

**How to detect?**

`fgets()`: prefill buffer with non-zero input. See if the characters after the first null character are all the pre-fill value.

`fscanf()`: Read a line with some size like `char buf[200]; fscanf(f, "%199[^\n]%n", buf, &length);` and use `length` for input length.  Additional code needed to handle end-of-line, extra-long lines, 0 length lines, etc.

`fgetc()`:  Build user code to read/handle as needed - tends to be slow.

**How to handle?**

In general, error out with a message or status.

If *null characters* are legitimate to this code's handling of text files, code needs to handle input, not as C *strings*, but as a buffer and length.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer. I do however have a question regarding the "how to detect the NUL with fgets()". Your suggestion sounds very reasonable, but it looks like a bit of a hack, as I think to prefill the buffer with any programmer-chosen, hard-coded character sounds bit like a workaround. Is this a standard practice among experienced C programmers?

Comment: Adding to my above comment. If you are going to simply go through the entire buffer to check NUL, wouldn't it be as efficient if we implement a while loop with fgetc() and write to the buffer character by character, at the same time checking the grabbed character?

Comment: @Learning_man, Experienced C programmers, when using `fgets()`, tend to ignore the potential of reading a _null character_ and use the input up to the first _null character_, be it the read one or appended one.  IMO, using extended library functions like `getline()` or `fscanf(f, "%199[^\n]%n",...` like code are the way to go.

Comment: @Learning_man Searching/writing a buffer is much less overhead that repeated `fgetc()` calls.  Consider any I/O function call a black-hole of time.  Idea: write some code to profile the various approaches - very educational exercise.